# about android google map

Tags: android, google-maps

As we all know, how to use google map with **system/framework/map.jar** with **user-library**.
But I encounter one problem, if the device doesn't have **system/framework/map.jar** in it's system, you application will do not work. So I want to put `map.jar` to our project as a *reference jar*, does this work? I have try it and remove **user-libray** line in `manifest.xml`. 
**but got  exception:**
`android java.lang.RuntimeException: stub`
does anyone know how to workaround?

Comment: I use the map.jar in sdkLocation\add-ons\google_apis-7_r01\libs\map.jar.  and I　use java decompile to see class source, found it all throw runtimeException("stub"); So I get map.jar for /system/framework/map.jar and get its classes.dex, decompile it and get map.jar and use it in my project. it throws exception dex error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I use "uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="false" "
then when I need googlemap, I check if our system contains this component, if contains, use it. if no, don't use.